# Http status 404 (Not Found) on jquery ajax GET to spring controller?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

My spring controller contains such get handler :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/country", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Region> getRegionsFor(@RequestParam(value = "countryName") String countryName,
            @RequestParam(value = "geonameId") Long geonameId) {
        logger.debug("fetching regions for {}, with geonameId {}", countryName, geonameId);
        RegionInfo regionInfo = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://api.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId={geonameId}&username=geonameUser2014",
                RegionInfo.class, geonameId);
        return regionInfo.getRegions();
    }
```

`@Controller` is mapped to `/hostel`. So url is `/hostel/country?countryName=%27&Albania%27&&geonameId=783754`

When I type in chrome browser

```
http://localhost:8080/HostMe/hostel/country?countryName=%27Albania%27&geonameId=783754
```

It returns json response as expected!!!

But I want to access this url with the following ajax call made with jquery:

```
 $.ajax({
            headers : {
                'Accept' : 'application/json'                   
            },
            url : '/hostel/country',
            dataType : 'json',
            data : {countryName:"Albania",geonameId:783754},
            type : 'GET',
            async : true,
            success : function(response) {
                console.log("response=" + response.join(','));
            },
            error : function(errorData) {
                console.log("data on fail ");
                printObject(errorData);
            }
            });
```

As you guess this doesn't work at all. Http status 404 (Not Found) is returned to `error:` handler .

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `url` in the ajax call is relative to the hostname. You need to add your web application context

```
url : '/HostMe/hostel/country',
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply! I changed url and it started to work.

Comment: Why when I set your url into `<spring:url>` it doesn't work and prints `unexpected token <`. Url `/hostel/country` also doesn't work with `<spring:url>`. I tried htmlEscape and javascriptEscape but it doesn't help. Only  setting your url inside ajax call works.

Comment: @volo Can you update your question with exactly what you're trying to do?